# How to set static IP address for Docker container in Windows?

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

I'm very new in Windows Docker and get stuck while setting up static IP for my Docker container. Below is docker-compose.yml file code, which I'm using to create a container.

```
version: '2'
services:
  pos:
    image: ${POS_IMAGE_TAG}
    container_name: ${POS_CONTAINER}
    restart: always
    ports:
      - ${POS_PORT}:${POS_PORT}
    networks:
      - widgets

  couchdb:
    image: ${COUCHDB_IMAGE_TAG}
    container_name: ${COUCHDB_CONTAINER}
    restart: always
    ports:
      - ${COUCHDB_PORT}:${COUCHDB_PORT}
    networks:
      - widgets
networks:
  widgets:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
     config:
       - subnet: 172.10.0.0/16
         gateway: 172.10.5.254
         aux_addresses:
          pos: 172.10.1.2
          couchdb: 172.10.1.3
```

when I run this, container gets created but I'm not able to access it on define IP's.

Comment: Please edit your title to remove the shouting, thanks. The `**` can be removed from the code block as well, I guess they should not be there?

Comment: @halfer - is it fine now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is very simple to add in docker version 1.10.1, build 9e83765.
1> Create your Docker Network (Docker_net).

```
docker network create --subnet=172.18.0.0/16 Docker_net
```

2> Run Image like

```
docker run --net Docker_net --ip 172.18.0.22 -it ubuntu bash
```

3> in Ububtu Shell

```
ip addr
```

You can also use addon

```
--hostname     //To Specify Hostname
--add-host     //for add more entries is etc/hosts
```

For references [Visit this site](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/#network-internal-mode)